# What algorithm does iOS use for Delta Updates

Tags: ios, updates

1. Do they use some algorithm such as the ones used in GDIFF program?
2. Do they ship the intermediate code to the user instead of iOS binary?
3. Why is it not possible do do a Delta update while updating iOS on Windows?

Comment: This is most likely information that is exclusive to Apple and their employees.  We can only theorize how it may or may not work therefore this question is probably better asked somewhere else.

Comment: By 'Delta' updates, are you referring to OTA updates?

Answer (score 3):

A delta update is defined as 'an update that only requires the user to download the code that has changed, not the whole program.'

iOS does, in fact, perform delta updates, and contradictory to Ralph's comment, we know exactly how it works.

- **Applications**

For iOS applications, delta updates are used to minimize the download size of new versions, to save internet traffic. Usually, the things that give a program most of its size are the static images and other media. During a simple update such as a bug fix, usually these static images stay the same, and there is no reason to send them over the network again. The only thing that is sent is the actual Mach-O binary containing the code that is buggy, along with whatever files have been changed.

So, delta updates most likely run by checksumming. When you submit an app update, Apple checks the checksum of all files submitted using some algorithm (most likley SHA1 or MD5) to scan for changes. If the executable has changed, but a certain image or other file has not, the image isn't packed with the update, as users have already downloaded it, and don't need to download it again. While this method may not pertain exactly to the definition of a delta update, as it includes executables along with other types of files, it has very similar concepts.

- **OTA Updates**

Apple uses delta updates in over-the-air updates for iOS as well. This is visible on any jailbroken iOS device. Updates are downloaded to `/var/MobileSofwareUpdate/softwareupdate.xxxx`, where `xxxx` presumbably is the build/release number. Each software update contains an image of the root filesystem, but not the entire version of iOS is included. Only the files that have changed from the version the user is currently on need to be replaced, and so only those files are included in the update package. The method for finding these changes is likley to be the same as with iOS apps, where checksumming finds changes in the files.

- **Algorithm**

Basically, to answer your question, Apple's algorithm doesn't send the differences between two individual files (similar to what you see in a git commit), but sends the entire updated file. Their 'algorithm' just looks for any change at all between the last version, and doesn't look for the actual change itself. This is proven by the fact that in OTA update packages, the complete files are available, and not just a log of the changes.

Comment: iOS 7 diffs the files and patches the existing files on your device inside your application bundle.